# Gnucash accounts not opening!

Tags: gnucash

I've used Gnucash for about a year now - Macintosh Version 3.3 Build 3.3+ (2018-09-29). Every month I open it and update the books, and output two reports. But today when opening, it gives a "-filename- could not be found.” message, and does not go to the accounts. I am very careful to not delete or move any of the files, but the file name it seeks does not exist. I find nothing in the gnucash online documentation, and cannot figure out how to ask for help on the IRC. What to do?

Comment: What filename? Also, what happened to/with your MacBook between now and the last time you could open GnuCash? Is that one month ago?

Comment: This sounds more like a general computing issue with a file having disappeared, in which case you might have better luck getting help on our sister site [apple.se]. That said, I do hope you get this sorted out.

Comment: Can you find the files? That is, is the problem that the files are gone, or that the files are there but Gnucash for some reason can't open them?

Comment: OK - thanks for all your responses. I carefully restored all the files from backup, and learned that one must open the correct file from within Gnucash. The backup held many .log files, but the one that must be opened is the "-accountname-.gnucash" file. Thank goodness that the backup actually worked! Thanks all again.